# Easy way of handling different user / pass for DB on dev. machine vs production server

Tags: php, mysql

I usually have a config-file with some global variables for database connectivity settings (such as db host, db name, user, pass).

I also really like to be able to just drag and drop all files from my dev machine to the production server. However, development db host etc may be different from the one on the production server.

Is there an easy way of, in PHP, saying something like **"if I'm on the dev-machine, use these values"**? (I'd prefer to avoid hacks based on host IP / name.) I'm thinking of something like perhaps setting something in php.ini or httpd.conf so that for instance `$DEV_MACHINE`, is set to true on the dev machine.

Comment: What's wrong with using the host name to set `production` and `development` flags? I'm curious to know.

Comment: Well I don't always use the same host name when reinstalling for instance. I wouldn't want to edit all my php files if I change my host-name from one install to another.

Comment: we have a .ini files with the domain names for different stagings (dev, client, production) and if it changes we only need to edit one file

Comment: If it was structured appropriately you wouldn't really have to edit *all* of the files? For example: I have a flag `IN_PRODUCTION`, in my index/bootstrap/whatever I usually do something along the lines of: `define('IN_PRODUCTION', (strpos ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'localhost') === FALSE`

Comment: No of course. I meant every config-file for *all* projects.

Comment: @Russell: Because the host name may not be reliable (Especially if you have a dedicated IP for the site).  Also, do you really want someone to be able to guess the host name of your dev site and access the debugging information on your production server (someone without authorization)?

Comment: @ircmaxell Your `Env` solution seems better. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up an Apache variable with `SetEnv`, and query it with PHP's `apache_getenv()`.

Comment: That's exactly what I do.  `SetEnv Environment Production`.  As long as you're using multiple servers, it's far better since you shouldn't always rely on the hostname (especially if you're using a dedicated IP).

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a file called `config-local.php` which is not under the source control.

If the file is absent, the app shows a warning page saying "finish the setup", or just runs a master to set up database credentials etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the URL. The dev url and the prod url should be different. And should be pretty stable.

But the ideal way is to keep the creds separated. You don't want the prod creds getting stolen if the dev server is hacked. So it is really best to suck it up and just keep them separate.